# Explain the 'MULTIPLE ENDING SUBROUTINE' in 8085

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8085

A subroutine is a group of instructions that will be used repeatedly in different locations of the program. Rather than repeat the same instructions several times, they can be grouped into a subroutine and than called at different locations... it can exist anywhere in the program even separately from the main program.

Subroutines generally used in microprocessor are:

1. Multiple ending subroutines
2. Nested subroutines
3. Multiple ending subroutine

I know what subroutine is, and I can also make a theory on 'multiple ending subroutine' on the basis of its name... BUT, I need a proper explanation of the same.

If anyone can explain all these three types of subroutines, that'll be great otherwise just explain "MULTIPLE ENDING SUBROUTINE" :)

Answer (score 1):

A google search on "MULTIPLE ENDING SUBROUTINE" would have given you [Microprocessor 8085 and Its Interfacing](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XWIepLsPN6EC&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=MULTIPLE+ENDING+SUBROUTINE&source=bl&ots=IMFYh6Mk-7&sig=AYYeJV08ZEmfhiaW6StlMG8x3CY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd3_OrnLXJAhXF1xoKHefpC1EQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=MULTIPLE%20ENDING%20SUBROUTINE&f=false).

It says that a *"MULTIPLE ENDING SUBROUTINE"* is a subroutine that because of conditions and test has more that one return point:

```
code...
...
JNC OTHER
...
RET
OTHER: ...
...
RET
```

You could also use one of the conditional return code of the 8085 (RC, RNC, ...)